# How do I store an unstrung berimbau?

Tags: equipment, capoeira, music

So, I finally own my own *berimbau*. I have successfully unstrung and restrung it a few times (although I'm still getting the hang of stringing it tightly enough). I've got a question though on how to handle it unstrung. Should I leave the *arame* (the string) hanging loose? Should I wrap it loosely around the *verga* (the main rod)? Loop it more tightly so that it's flush?

Comment: As you're talking about unstringing and restringing, have you thought about how an archer stores their bow?

Comment: That is possible, but it seems like there's a difference in strong materials, whether the string gets removed entirely, etc.

Comment: As a side note, I've learned that leaning it up in a corner is a bad idea. My wife swears that it just fell on its own, but I have my doubts...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not relevant to martial arts.

Comment: @coinbird Music is an essential part of Capoeira, and the berimbau is the primary instrument played during the sparring, but I respect your opinion.

Comment: @SeanDuggan No need to respect my opinion, I may be flat out wrong here. I suppose the definition of martial arts is more broad than I'd like. Allowing this would seem to invite questions about ballet, and care for the pianos playing ballet music.

Comment: @coinbird: :-D Combat ballet?

Comment: While I'm normally aggressive on scope, I feel that questions on maintenance and care of martial arts equipment is in scope, and I'm willing to accept that the berimbau is part of that equipment.  I agree that it is .. odd... but we get so few questions on MA:SE that it seems we can err on the side of inclusivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our academia berimbaus are hanging on a wall unstrung. Generally, we do not remove the string from the "tuning" end, we just let it loose but it's still wrapped around the upper part. In other words, it looks almost like tuned berimbau except that string is not tightened.

Comment: Ah. Good. That's how I'd been doing it, but there was a part of me paranoid that I was going to mess with the tension in some way.

Comment: I think much more important is the temperature and humidity in which you store the instrument :)